# Is there a way to make my image equal the size of the navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, navigation, image-resizing, responsive

Is there a way that I can make the `width` of my `navigation bar` the same `width` as the image. The problem is I'm working with an image that has an original size of `497 x 298px` but to make the image stretch the full width of the page whilst still having `margins` of `10px` on either side I had to set `width: 98.4%`.

Also, for some reason when I set the `ul` to `width 100%` the navigation is way too long and only fits within a normal desktop screen if I make it 50%. So at the moment they are both the same length, but when I resize the page they start to go out of sync with only the ul element following the rules I've set.

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  padding-left: 32%;
  padding-right: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #F25f70;
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)
}
img {
  width: 98.4%;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just wrap your navigation in a `<div>`. Give it 100% width. Then assign a `background-image` to your `<ul>` and make that 98% width. including these background properties

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

I created a 

[## DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/egL8t4db/8/)

woohooo moving to Cali in a week!!! So I made it Cali themed.

Note: The Image I used is the same dimensions specified in your post.

Also you may wana check out the [background-size properties at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)